# Close Button on FancyBox Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

When I click the close button of my FancyBox nothing happens.
It will only close when I click outside the frame. How can I get the close button to work?

Comment: Fancybox, which version, 1.3 or 2.0? Did you refer the API documentation they have?

Comment: can you share your code? Fancybox has some options, one is closeClick another is closeBtn. Are those set to TRUE / FALSE?

Comment: 'showCloseButton' set to "true"

Comment: Actually, the x close button works with Explorer, Firefox but dosen't work with Chrome. I have fancyBox 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Just call `$.fn.fancybox.close()`or `$.fancybox.close(true)` on your onClick event

Comment: But the built-in close function, with the circled X in the upper right, should do this without having to call the `$.fancybox.close()` unless something else is going on...